# PostCSS plugin postcss-preset-env requires PostCSS 8

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, npm

I've tried to put my package.json file in but the site is protesting:

> E:\VSC_Workspace\Purgecss\src\scss\main.scss:undefined:undefined: PostCSS plugin postcss-preset-env requires PostCSS 8.

I follow this video youtube I have shown below. Basically it is good and explanatory, but even if I follow it I get problems. Maybe because

Parcel JS Setups Walkthrough and Review Swashbuckling with Code

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour], then revise your post to improve communication. References are made on the internet with _links_, not plain text. (Link your video.) However, questions must be self-sustaining, so you need to put more information in yours.